# How to retrieve stage from UI control in JavaFX

Tags: controls, javafx-2, stage

The question is pretty simple, but I haven't found any examples relating to this.
I want to obtain the containing Stage of a UI Control in JavaFX. Is there a way to do this?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
((Stage) Control.getScene().getWindow())
```